# Office365 disable push notification for specific changes

Tags: java, push-notification, outlook, office365, office365api

I'm trying to save events and calendars in my database and then send the request to Office365 to create/update it there. The problem is that, when event or calendar is changed outside my app, I want my app to get push notifications, but when my app changes the event, I don't want to get any notification about this change. Is there a way to inform Office365 via REST API that I don't want to have any notifications about the event that I post to it? Can't find it in the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#get-events

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#event

Hope there should be a way either header or parameter to disable push notifications for particular requests. 
Thanks!